# How to update the action which behind a custom menu

Tags: contributions, reports, menu

We have a custom menu which has been created years ago and the one in charge is not with us anymore. The menu makes a contribution extraction and generates a pdf.
The menu open a page on the url page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcdntaxreceipts%2Fcheques&reset=1.

We would like to update the pdf content. Does anyone can tell us where we can find where the extract and pdf content ha been defined.
Thks

Answer (score 1):

Under Administer - System Settings - Directories you'll see one for "Extensions Directory" that will have the path to a folder. If you look at that folder in the filesystem you'll see all the custom extensions, one per subfolder.

It may look like `[civicrm.files]/ext`. If you look near the top of the page there's a blue help icon - if you click it it will tell you the full path for `[civicrm.files]`.

[image]

Comment: Thks but I don't follow. What I am supposed to after I had the directory information for extension ? Are ou telling me that the menu is an extension ?

Comment: Yes the code that handles that menu option will be in an extension. There may also be a related message template at Administer - CiviMail - Message Templates that it uses to populate/generate the pdf. That url for cheques that you mention is not part of the cdntaxreceipts extension, so is some custom code that will be in another extension.